# How to represent flexible data models in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm quite new to the world of data persistence and Core Data and I have a hard time representing a model for my app.

My app is a collection of forms and will feature a "template editor" that allows the user to choose what fields should these forms contain. For example, an user might want to create forms with the fields "name", "age" and "picture". Those three attributes can all be of different types (String, Int, and Data). Moreover, there's no guarantee what the user will select. They could add 45 different fields including custom ones (with their own titles) if they wanted.

My question is **what would be an efficient way to model one of these forms in Core Data?**

I thought about representing every attribute in the model, or making a dictionary attribute with all the fields… But since I'm a beginner, I'm afraid of making a wrong technical choice that could hurt the app's efficiency or ability to execute predicates, etc.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use this simple design for your models?. Here they are represented as structs but they are easily translated to entities

```
struct Form {
    var name: String
    var fields: [Field]
}

struct Field {
    var name: String
    var type: String //Maybe an enum in code
    //var form: Form :in a struct you don't have this property but your entity will have it as a relationship
}
```

Comment: This is great! I just have another question. How would you represent the Field's value in Core Data? Given that it could represent, a string, a number or an image among others…

Answer (score 1):

Since user can add `n` number of fields in a template, **adding every fields into the DB is not good idea**. This will lead to a big size and this will volute the db normalisation.

Better to **convert the template into single json** which can be stored in a file based on template name or id. If you have a DB already then you can link the file name into a user object. Same json can be used to upload to server or render the template again from the same json file.

Even you can position the fields based on `id` else even you can added `position` field in the json in order to maintain the field orders.

**Example:**

```
{
  "template_id": "xyz",
  "fields": {
    "textfield": [
      {
        "label": "First Name",
        "value": "Stack",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "Last Name",
        "value": "Overflow",
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "image": [
      {
        "label": "Profile Photo",
        "value": "/Document/Images/Profile.jpeg",
        "id": 3
      }
    ],
    "date_picker": [
      {
        "label": "DOB",
        "value": "01/01/1980",
        "id": 4
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe dictionary model is best for this because you don't know what n how many fields user is going to use. But you can save those fields values in to string type and store it in ur core data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Microsoft Excel` to prototype and design a database. Once it's done, create your CoreData model.